# Centrar form C#

Tags: c#

Hola al presionar el boton sale X form pero sale donde quiere, quiero que salga en el centro, probe algunas cosas y no me ha funcionado

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DepuracionInfo frm3 = new DepuracionInfo();

        frm3.Show(this);
        frm3.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    }
```

Así el codigo funciona pero no centra, eso es lo que llevo.

Comment: Ya intentaste primero en establecer la posicion de inicio y luego hacer el show.

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar y el problema persiste

Comment: Gracias tu respuesta me ayudo algo en solucionarlo

Comment: Entonce te funciono con [ShowDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567083).

Comment: En parte, ya le habia puesto showDialog y no habia funcionado pero al poner primero en establecer la posicion al inicio luego showDialog funciono, gracias

Answer (score 3):

Selecciona tu formulario y en propiedades busca la opcion StartPosition y selecciona CenterScreen.

Answer (score 1):

Funciona así, gracias

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DepuracionInfo frm3 = new DepuracionInfo();
        frm3.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        frm3.ShowDialog();

    }
```

Comment: puedes evitar al menos una línea de código si lo haces así: var frm3 = new DepuracionInfo { StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent }; es decir, en una sola línea inicializas el formulario y además inicializas la propiedad StartPosition.